# dynamically allocate contiguous block of memory for 2D array of unknown data type in C 89/90 using single call to malloc

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, contiguous

I must dynamically allocate a contiguous block of storage to hold a 2D array of an arbitrary data type.
It can only use a single call to `malloc`.
Part of the memory must include the mixed data types of "pointer to data type" and the data type itself.
The arbitrary data type is called `Type`. 
Full disclosure: yes, this is for an assignment.  I've been beating my head on this for a good 30+ hours trying to figure this out. I cannot use C99+ standards.  It must be Pre-C99.

I so far have this:

```
Type **Create2D(size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    Type **ptr = (Type **)SafeMalloc(rows * sizeof(Type*) + rows * cols * sizeof(Type)); 
    //  rows*sizeof(Type*) is total memory needed for the elements to store the pointers. 
    //  rows*cols*sizeof(Type) is the memory needed to store the actual array data
    //  The sum of the above two gives the total amount of contiguous memory needed

    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < (int)rows; index++)
        ptr[index] = &ptr + rows*sizeof(Type *) + index * cols * sizeof(Type);
        //  in my mind, this assigns the pointers to the address of each column
        //  to the first address blocks allocated by malloc
}
```

the `Type` data type is defined by a provided header file using a `typedef` as follows:

```
#define ELEMENTS 9
typedef signed char Type[ELEMENTS];
#undef ELEMENTS
```

the SafeMalloc function just contains an error check along with the malloc call

```
static Type **SafeMalloc(size_t size) {
    void *vp;       
    if ((vp = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return(vp);
}
```

My Create2D function is called from main as follows, where `rows` and `cols` are set to varying values provided by a for loop so that they change each run through the listed code here:

```
Type **ppobj;
int rows, cols;
ppobj = Create2D((size_t)rows, (size_t)cols);
```

The array is called and tested in another loop here:

```
int x = Test2D(ppObj, rows, cols);
```

Defined as:

```
int Test2D(Type **ppObj, int dim0, int dim1) {
    signed char testValue;
    int row, col, ix;       
    Type item;

    testValue = SCHAR_MIN;  
    for (row = 0; row < dim0; ++row) {
        for (col = 0; col < dim1; ++col) {
            for (ix = 0; ix < (int)(sizeof(item) / sizeof(item[0])); ++ix) {                
                ppObj[row][col][ix] = testValue;
                //  throws an exception in above step while stepping through at col = 1.
                if (testValue == SCHAR_MAX)
                    testValue = SCHAR_MIN;
                else
                   ++testValue;
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Finally, I think what I have is close.  Given a 1x27 array, it will make it through this, but when my function for freeing the memory is called and then a 2x26 array is called it will error in the above step.  It's made it to the 3x25 array and erred above as well.  My free function looks like this:

```
void Free2D(void *ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
```

it is called using this sytax, from the above main function:

```
Free2D((void *)ppObj);
```

I've also run it through and seen the `dim1` variable change in the middle of the nested for loops from it's set value from the passed arguments to something just huge like 1830342 or some sort.  It makes me believe the `free()` function is not being used properly by me.

Comment: 30+ hours! wow, that's a long time... you got the idea, but the method to compute the pointers is incorrect, you must compute byte offsets from `ptr` cast as a byte pointer.  See my answer for additional details.

Comment: The address of the elements past `rows * sizeof(Type*)` - the pointers - is not guaranteed to be suitably aligned for use to store a value of `Type`.  For example, if `rows` is odd, `sizeof( Type * )` is 4 bytes, and `Type` has an 8-byte alignment restriction.  Unless you want to get into doing alignment calculations, you're better off doing *two* allocations - one for the array of pointers, and one for the array data.

Comment: " It must be Pre-C99." - I guess this is the same reason they teach Latin at high school

Comment: `I must dynamically allocate a contiguous block of storage to hold a 2D array` Please stop calling a `Pointer` =>> `Array`.

Comment: pointer to pointer is hard to manage (you have two arrays to deallocate: the array itself and the array of pointers to the start of each row) and is bad performance if not `restricted.` use linear indexing if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the formula to compute `ptr[index]` is incorrect: you must compute byte offsets from `ptr` cast as a byte pointer.

Here is a better version:

```
Type **Create2D(size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    Type **ptr = (Type **)SafeMalloc(rows * sizeof(Type*) + rows * cols * sizeof(Type)); 
    //  rows*sizeof(Type*) is total memory needed for the elements to store the pointers. 
    //  rows*cols*sizeof(Type) is the memory needed to store the actual array data
    //  The sum of the above two gives the total amount of contiguous memory needed

    size_t index;
    for (index = 0; index < rows; index++) {
        ptr[index] = (Type*)((unsigned char*)ptr + rows * sizeof(Type *) + index * cols * sizeof(Type));
       //  in my mind, this assigns the pointers to the address of each column
       //  to the first address blocks allocated by malloc
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

There is still a potential alignment issue: `Type` may require a stricter alignment than `Type*`.  To account for this, you can compute the index size separately and align the data part on a multiple of the size of `Type`:

```
Type **Create2D(size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    size_t index_size = (size_t)((unsigned long long)(rows * sizeof(Type*)) * sizeof(Type) / sizeof(Type));
    Type **ptr = (Type **)SafeMalloc(index_size + rows * cols * sizeof(Type)); 
    //  index_size is total memory needed for the elements to store the pointers. 
    //  rows*cols*sizeof(Type) is the memory needed to store the actual array data
    //  The sum of the above two gives the total amount of contiguous memory needed

    size_t index;
    for (index = 0; index < rows; index++) {
        ptr[index] = (Type*)((unsigned char*)ptr + index_size + index * cols * sizeof(Type));
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: That's also not guaranteed to meet any alignment restrictions on `Type`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: `malloc` return value `ptr` is guaranteed to meet alignment restrictions on `Type`, adding a multiple of `sizeof(Type)` keeps this constraint verified. How do you think the alignment restriction is not met?

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
I have tried the first of the two samples and it works.  I understand the typecasting the entire index calculation to a (Type*), but I don't understand the typecast of (unsigned char*)ptr.  I've tried removing that portion and my program hangs on the free(ptr) function.  could you help me understand what that typecast is doing?
@AndrewHenle I completely agree that doing this in two allocations is far easier.  Sadly I'm restricted in my ability to do that right now due to the scope of my instructions.

Comment: Casting `ptr` as `(unsigned char*)` or `(char*)` allows pointer arithmetic to be performed on byte addresses as opposed to multiples of the size of `Type`.  In the second code, it is possible to with a different cast: `ptr[index] = (Type*)ptr + index_size / sizeof(Type) + index * cols;` but I find it less explicit.

Comment: That rings clear as  a bell.  Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: @chqrlie *malloc return value ptr is guaranteed to meet alignment restrictions on Type, adding a multiple of sizeof(Type) keeps this constraint verified. How do you think the alignment restriction is not met?*  I noted your updates.  That's why I recommended in my comments above to do two allocations - that avoids the alignment math that some later coder maintaining the code might have to figure out.  And that later coder might very well be me at 3 AM trying to fix a critical issue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Of course in a real life example, one would allocate the pointers and the data separately. In C99, one would not even need the pointers and use VLAs.  But the OP explicitly stated his constraint: *It can only use a single call to malloc.*  Probably an assignment to assess his understanding of memory layout.